# Checkbox values to varchar via Spring

Tags: java, forms, spring

I am trying to get a varchar message from a database to display the selected values of a checkbox field in a jsp for patient's medication's dosage frequency.  The possible values will be saved in comma-delimited string in the varchar.  For most form fields there is simply a one form value to one database field ratio, but in this case, I am needing to merge the values that would come as a string[] into the comma-delimited string and then when retrieving that record for that medication of that patient, display the selected values from the comma-delimited string as selected from the selectableDosageFrequencyList.

You assistance in this is greatly appreciated as I am not sure what I am missing here.

In the application context, I created the list of possible values as part of the ServiceBean.

```
    <property name="selectableDosageFrequencyList">
        <set>
            <value>On an empty stomach</value>
            <value>Every other day</value>
            <value>4 times daily</value> 
            <value>3 times daily</value>
            <value>Twice daily</value>
            <value>At bedtime</value> 
            <value>With meal</value>
            <value>As needed</value>
            <value>Once daily</value>               
        </set>
    </property>
```

This is set up in the flow as requestscope.

```
<view-state id="addEditMedication" model="medication">

    <on-render>
        <set name="requestScope.selectableDosageFrequencyList" value="memberService.buildSelectableDosageFrequencyList(patient)" />     
    </on-render>
...
    <transition on="next" to="assessment" >
        <evaluate expression="memberService.updateMedication(patient, medication)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

I have helper methods in the memberService that need to be executed when the form is init and then when the form is completed.

```
    //get the form fields selected and build the new string for db
public String setSelectedDosageFrequency(String [] dosageFrequencies){
    String frequencies = null;
    if (dosageFrequencies != null){
        for (String s : dosageFrequencies){
            frequencies = frequencies + "," + s;
        }
    }
    return frequencies;
}
//get value from database and build selected Set
public LinkedHashSet<String> getSelectedDosageFrequencyList(String dosageFrequency){
    String copyOfDosages =dosageFrequency;//may not need to do this
    LinkedHashSet<String> setofSelectedDosageFrequency = new LinkedHashSet<String> ();
    while (copyOfDosages!= null && copyOfDosages.length()>0){
        for (String aFrequency: selectableDosageFrequencyList){
        if (copyOfDosages.contains(aFrequency)){
            setofSelectedDosageFrequency.add(aFrequency);
            if (!copyOfDosages.equals(aFrequency) && copyOfDosages.endsWith(aFrequency)){
                copyOfDosages.replaceAll(","+aFrequency, "");       
            }else if (!copyOfDosages.equals(aFrequency) && copyOfDosages.contains(aFrequency=",")){
                copyOfDosages.replaceAll(aFrequency+",", "");
            }else
                copyOfDosages.replaceAll(aFrequency, "");
            copyOfDosages.trim();
        }
        }
    }   
    return setofSelectedDosageFrequency;        
}
```

The Medication class that backs the form will have a variable for dosage-frequency as a string.

```
private String dosageFrequency;
```

The jsp I currently am doing this.

```
        <div class="formField">
            <form:label path="dosageFrequency">Dosage Frequency</form:label>
            <ul class="multi-column double" style="width: 550px;">
                <form:checkboxes path="dosageFrequency" items="${selectableDosageFrequencyList}" itemLabel="${selectableDosageFrequencyList}" element="li" />
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at this some more, I have a solution and hopefully this can help someone else with a similar issue.  Oh and changed the delimiter to a space ' ' rather than , :

The webflow and the app context doesnt change but because since the view-state id="addEditMedication"... is transitioned into the view state using the initMedication(patient) method and the transition out of the view state uses the memberService.updateMedication(patient, med). I updated the memberServiceImpl with :

```
@Override
public Medication initMedication(PatientInformation patient, int index) {
    ServiceUtils.assertNotNull("A patient is required", patient);
    Medication medication = patient.getMedicationList().get(index);
    medication.setDosageFrequencySet(
                  convertSelectedDosageFrequencyList(medication.getDosageFrequency()));
    return medication;
}

@Override
public void updateMedication(PatientInformation patient, Medication medication) {
    if (!patient.getMedicationList().contains(medication)){
        medication.setDosageFrequency(
               convertSelectedDosageFrequency(medication.getDosageFrequencySet()));
        patient.getMedicationList().add(medication);
    }
}

private String convertSelectedDosageFrequency(LinkedHashSet<String> dosageFrequencies){
    String frequencies = StringUtils.join(dosageFrequencies," ");
    return frequencies;
}

private  LinkedHashSet<String> convertSelectedDosageFrequencyList(String dosageFrequency){
    String copyOfDosages =dosageFrequency;
    LinkedHashSet<String> setofSelectedDosageFrequency = new LinkedHashSet<String> ();
    if  (copyOfDosages!= null && copyOfDosages.length()>0){
        for (String aFrequency: selectableDosageFrequencyList){
        if (copyOfDosages.contains(aFrequency)){
            setofSelectedDosageFrequency.add(aFrequency);
            copyOfDosages = copyOfDosages.replaceAll(aFrequency, "");
            copyOfDosages = copyOfDosages.trim();
        }
        }
    }   
    return setofSelectedDosageFrequency;        
}
```

the Medication class is updated with:

```
private String dosageFrequency;
private LinkedHashSet<String> dosageFrequencySet;
//hibernate mapped
public String getDosageFrequency() {
    return dosageFrequency;
}
public void setDosageFrequency(String dosageFrequency) {
    this.dosageFrequency = dosageFrequency;
}
public LinkedHashSet<String> getDosageFrequencySet() {
    return dosageFrequencySet;
}
public void setDosageFrequencySet(LinkedHashSet<String> dosageFrequencySet) {
    this.dosageFrequencySet = dosageFrequencySet;
}
```

The jsp is updated with

```
        <div class="formField">
            <form:label path="dosageFrequency">Dosage Frequency</form:label>
            <ul class="multi-column double" style="width: 550px;">
                <form:checkboxes id="dosageFrequencySet" path="dosageFrequencySet" items="${selectableDosageFrequencyList}" element="li" />
            </ul>
        </div>
```